# Using Combo Box in Bot Framework

Tags: combobox, botframework, adaptive-cards

I need to use a combo box in the bot conversation to show a list of items, so that the user can select on from it.

i don't know whether its possible to use combo box in Bot framework. I did search in the internet and found PromptDialog.Choice but this is not what i want to do. Ca anyone please help?

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use advanced controls such as a combo box, you should consider using [Adaptive Cards](http://adaptivecards.io/).

For example, the [Calendar sample](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/#CalendarReminder) is showing a combo box.

[image]

The only thing to have in mind is that Adaptive Cards is not yet fully supported in all the channels. You should review the [Channel Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status) to check the support for Adaptive Cards in your channel.

Comment: can you please provide more information on how can i use adaptive cards in ma project and where should i use them its confusing as am new to this ;(

Comment: Check the adaptive cards samples at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-samples